# How to integrate Rasa bot on Slack on Multiple Workspace?

Tags: slack, rasa

**Context:** I have built a simple rasa bot and integrated it with Slack as per the details provided in the [Rasa doc](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/1.10.7/user-guide/connectors/slack/).
To share this bot on another Slack workspace, have implemented the Oauth and the bot is thus successfully installed in other workspaces as well.

**Issue:** The bot only replies to the user in my development Workspace and not in any other. How can
I enable this for other workspaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the Rasa Open Source maintainers.

The current Rasa Open Source [Slack channel implementation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/slack/) doesn't support multiple workspaces. Rasa Open Source enables you to implement and use [custom channels](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/connectors/custom-connectors/) which you could use to extend the current (or do a new) implementation of the Slack channel. Would be cool to see this being contributed to the official project or released as an extra library!

Comment: Hi Tobias, Thank you so much for your reply. I indeed have created a custom implementation that handles the connection to multiple workspaces where the app is installed.